# Can 32 bit floats between zero and one be compared (with the same outcome) if they're transmuted to int/uint?

Tags: c, casting, floating-point

When representing two float32's as int32 or uint32 (using union or casting pointer types), Within a limited range (0..1), can these values be compared against each other, that would match the result of the comparison when executed as floats?

Example:

```
int float_as_int(float f) {
    union { int i; float f; } u;
    u.f = f;
    return u.i;
}

/* Assert the following is always true for values in a limited range. */
void assert_compare_works_as_expected(float a, float b) {
    assert(float_as_int(a) < float_as_int(b) == a < b);
}

/* Psudocode */
int main() {
    for f in 0..1 {
        assert_compare_works_as_expected(f_prev, f);
        f_prev = f;
    }
}
```

If not, what float ranges map directly to ints so comparison can be done?

Comment: Float accepts values up to `3.402823 × 10^38` while `uint32_t` up to `(2^32)-1`. You are safe until your float is not bigger than maximal value of int you are casting to.

Comment: A `float` in the range `INT_MIN` to `INT_MAX`.

Comment: C++ may be a bit easier to work with in this instance because of `numeric_limits`. I suppose the same could be done in C using the defines. Also see [Normalized Integer to/from Float Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37580501/608639) and [Convert/Quantize Float Range to Integer Range](https://stackoverflow.com/q/599976/608639)

Comment: According to your modified question, answer is no. They can't be compared as float structure is completely different to int structure.

Comment: There is no requirement in C as to how `float` should be represented.

Comment: @WeatherVane that's true, but since most of them have IEEE 754 standard implemented, we can say that answer is still no.

Comment: @tilz0R If we assume IEEE 754 standard for representing floats then the comparison should be valid directly. Because exponents are stored before the mantissa.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya For example, number `4` in `int` is represented as `0x00000004` while the same number `4` is represented in float (by IEEE754 standard) as `0x40800000`. How is this the same?

Comment: @tilz0R Yes, 4 is 0x40800000 in float but 5.0 is 0x40a00000. The comparison   `0x40800000 < 0x40a00000 -> 4.0 < 5.0`

Comment: @tilz0R OP is not comparing a float with other unsigned. I believe he is type punning 2 floats into unsigned integers and comparing the integers.

Comment: **You cannot cast the pointer**, it is UB, and it will bite you. The compilers will keep the floats in floating point registers, they're not flushed into memory upon access to some int pointer.

Comment: @WeatherVane [Almost completely right](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4142924/weather-vane) A  float in the range `[INT_MIN.99999.... to INT_MAX.99999....]` as conversion from `float` to `int` is defined for a slightly larger range.

Comment: @chux agree its not great, I didn't think the question would be misunderstood as it was, I've since added an example in the question.

Comment: @unalignedmemoryaccess: IEEE 754 floats bias the exponent so floats of increasing magnitude have monotonically increasing bit-patterns.  Other than being a sign/magnitude vs. 2's complement format, you actually *can* use integer compares on float bit-patterns, including subnormals and +Infinity but not NaN.  (Not that you'd usually want to in C, since the type-punning is inconvenient.)  Fun fact: `nextafterf(x, +-INFINITY)` can be implemented as an integer increment or decrement of the FP bit-pattern after checking for special cases like NaN (or Infinity since it has to saturate on overflow)

Comment: Related: [Why does the integer representation of a floating point number offer a piecewise linear approximation to the logarithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75772363)

Answer (score 3):

The long answer is: **Yes**, but with multiple restrictions and caveats.
Comparing floats in the range `0` to `1` as integers may yield the correct result in many cases.  As a matter of fact, the values need not be restricted to this range:

- Assuming the `float` type has 32-bit single precision IEEE-754 representation and the `int` type has 32-bit 2's complement representation without padding bits (ie `int` is `int32_t`);
- Assuming neither of the `float` values are NaN;
- Assuming the values are in normal or sub-normal form;
- Assuming `float` and `int` representations have the same endianness in memory;
- if the values are equal, comparing as `int` will yield the correct result unless you are comparing `+0.0` and `-0.0`.
- if the values are not both negative, the comparison as `int` may indeed yield the correct result, but the C Standard makes no guarantee and accessing the `float` values as `int` breaks the strict aliasing rule in most circumstances.
- if the values are both negative and the other constraints are matched, the comparison result should be negated.

For your side question: some integer values may indeed have an identical representation as `int` and `float`, notably `0`, but the floating point value `-0.0` has a different representation yet compares equal to `0.0` as `float`. There are only two other special cases of integers that have the same representation as `int32_t` and IEEE-754 `float`: `1318926965` (`0x4E9D3A75`) and `-834214802` (`0xCE46E46E`).

You can look at the actual representation of floating point values for the IEEE format, overwhelmingly common but not mandated by the C Standard here:

- [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)
- [Single-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)

For your specific case, if you know the values are in the range `0` to `1`, the only special case you should handle is the negative `0`. You can for the sign as positive by masking the value and the code will look like:

```
/* return 0 if p1 and p2 point to the same float value,
   -1 if p1 points to a smaller value and
   +1 otherwise.
 */
int compare_floats_as_ints(const int32_t *p1, const int32_t *p2) {
    int32_t i1 = *p1 & 0x7fffffff;
    int32_t i2 = *p2 & 0x7fffffff;
    return (i1 > i2) - (i1 < i2);
}
```

Comment: If the exponent is stored before the mantissa (and a single cohurt is enforced), the constraint *if the values are within the same range of powers of 2* can be relaxed right?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: if the values are not both negative, it seems the comparison as int can work for some architectures. Interesting.

Comment: Note that this question is **specifically** about values from 0 to 1. But this answer is phrased as if the question is about all floating point values (which won't work of course). To the question I asked, the short answer is **Yes** AFAICS, note that while I did edit the question heavily, the 0..1 part was there from the start.

Comment: @ideasman42: indeed the answer is yes, if a number of conditions are met and the values are not `+0.0` and `-0.0`.

Answer (score 2):

The way I interpret you question: When interpreting the bit pattern of a floating point number in memory as a int, will the usual comparison operators behave the same for floating point numbers and integers.

The answer is no. Strictly speaking, the C standard has a few possible integer representations and even more possible float representations. But even limiting ourselves to what pretty much everyone does - two's complement integers and ieee754 binary32 floating point, the answer is still no.

The simplest example: floating points have two zeroes. The bit pattern 0x00000000 and the bit pattern 0x80000000 represent the numbers 0 and -0. They both compare equal as floating point, they wouldn't if interpreted as integers. Then you have two infinities, and a whole lot of bit patterns that represent NaN.

You could enumerate the special cases and avoid them and then I'm pretty sure that a comparison as integers would work, but whatever performance gain you get from integer comparisons (which I assume is the point here) you'd gain you'd lose much more in avoiding the special cases.

Responding to your last edit: Yes, in the range 0 to 1, the bit pattern for ieee754 floating point numbers is such that when interpreted as integers the normal integer comparison operators will behave the way you want. It's a bad idea, but it would work.

Answer (score 2):

> Can 32 bit floats between zero and one be compared (with the same outcome) if they're transmuted to int/uint?

Using a `union` will work for comparing `float` in the range (zero and one) and  **if** all the list below can be insured.

Otherwise the general answer is no.  It might work, it might not.

```
union x {
  float f;
  int32_t i;
  uint32_t u;
} a,b ;
a.f = foo(); 
b.f = foo(); 
// for all a.f and b.f in range
assert((a.u > b.u) == (a.f > b.f));
assert((a.u < b.u) == (a.f < b.f));
assert((a.u == b.u) == (a.f == b.f));
// also for a.i
```

1. `float` is [binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)
2. The integer type is not padded. (example: `(u)intN_t`) types.
3. The integer may be any encoding: 2's complement, 1's complement, sign-magnitude
4. The integer has same endian as `float`.  C does not require this.
5. The integer/FP type size are the same. (This was implied in the question).

This also works for the extended range of [+0.0 ... +INF].  It does not hold for -0.0.

---

To compare 2 *any* finite/infinite `float` given the same endian-ness, expected `float` encoding and the above conditions:

```
int32_t sequence_f(float x) {
  union {
    float f;
    int32_t i32;
    uint32_t u32;
  } u;
  assert(sizeof(float) == sizeof(uint32_t));
  u.f = x;
  if (u.i32 < 0) {
    u.u32 = 0x80000000 - u.u32;
  }
  //  printf("% 16.8e % 11d\n", x, u.i32);
  return u.i32;
}

// return + +,0,- without FP math.
// valid for all finite/infinite values, not valid for NaN
// +0.0 -0.0 compare the same.
int compare(float fa, float fb) {
  int32_t ia = sequence_f(fa);
  int32_t ib = sequence_f(fb);
  return (ia > ib) - (ia < ib);
}
```

This is useful for embedded applications that need to perform FP compare, yet not other FP math.

---

In general, casting is UB due to anti-aliasing.

Comment: quite an elegant way to handle negative values including `-0.0`.

Comment: @chqrlie For C99 onward, yes  type punning is OK  [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11639947/2410359)

Comment: `int32_t` is guaranteed to be 32-bit 2's complement with no padding, so you only need points 1 and 4 in your list

Comment: @M.M Agree - could minimize to those 2, yet `(u)int32_t` are example integer types.  General types would need additional conditions, as you say, that are all ready satisfied with the classic fixed-width types and binary32.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, with the qualifications that:

- float & int are the same size.
- inputs are positive, float values that don't include:
  `-0.0`, `-inf`, `nan`, `-nan`.

Details:

- Both `signed int` and `unsigned int` can be used with matching comparisons.
- Assumes IEEE754 32bit floating point.
- Both int & float need to be the same endian *(do architectures exist where this is not the case?)*
- Not just `0-1`, `0.0..FLT_MAX` and `inf` can be compared.
- For completeness, negative values: `-0.0..-FLT_MAX` can be compared too but will always have a flipped order, eg:
  `assert(float_as_int(a) > float_as_int(b) == a < b);`

In this case, 2x floats represented as ints can be compared, giving the same results.

Here is a evidence that this can work:

C code, tests the full, unsigned float range.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned step = 0;
    union {
        float f;
        unsigned u;
    } value;

    value.f = 0.0;

    unsigned u_prev = value.u;

    while (value.f != FLT_MAX) {
        value.f = nextafterf(value.f, FLT_MAX);
        unsigned u = value.u;
        if (u <= u_prev) {
            printf("At value %f, step %u, comparisons don't match\n", value.f, step);
            break;
        }
        u_prev = u;
        step++;
    }
    printf("Tested %u times\n", step);

    return 0;
}
```

a Python3 script, checking all values from 0-1 with `nextafterf`, note that this is slow *(hence the C version above)*.

```
def main():
    from struct import pack, unpack
    as_u32_prev = None
    value = 0.0
    while True:
        # transmute float to int
        as_u32 = unpack('I', pack('f', value))
        if as_u32_prev is not None:
            if as_u32_prev > as_u32:
                raise Exception("f32/u32 comparisons don't match")
        as_u32_prev = as_u32
        if value == 1.0:
            break
        value = nextafterf(value, 1.0)

# Boiler Plate, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063755

import ctypes
import sys
from sys import platform as _platform

if _platform == "linux" or _platform == "linux2":
    _libm = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libm.so.6')
    _funcname_f = 'nextafterf'
elif _platform == "darwin":
    _libm = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libSystem.dylib')
    _funcname_f = 'nextafterf'
elif _platform == "win32":
    _libm = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('msvcrt.dll')
    _funcname_f = '_nextafterf'
else:
    # these are the ones I have access to...
    # fill in library and function name for your system math dll
    print("Platform", repr(_platform), "is not supported")
    sys.exit(0)

nextafterf = getattr(_libm, _funcname_f)
nextafterf.restype = ctypes.c_float
nextafterf.argtypes = [ctypes.c_float, ctypes.c_float]

main()
```

---

Note that other answers here say that this wont work in all cases,
I'd be interested to know which cases the examples in this answer would fail, *(besides architectures where float and int aren't 4 bytes in size)*.

Comment: For example, number `4` in `int` is represented as `0x00000004` while the same number `4` is represented in float (by IEEE754 standard) as `0x40800000`. How is this the same?

Comment: The values are not the same, but the comparison is (when both values are transmuted to ints and compared) - for values 0-1 at least.

Comment: @chqrlie are you sure? - the C code above deals only with positive floats.

Comment: "qualification that inputs are positive, normalized float values" should be "qualification that inputs are positive, float values".  normal and sub-normals work

Comment: A key element missing is the _assumption_ that the endian of `float` and `int` are the same.  There are not specified to be so.  So this is a failing case.

Comment: Also missing: is the _assumption_ `float`, and `unsigned` are the same size and `unsigned` has no padding - a failing case.  Part of this was implied in the question, yet "float32's as int32 or uint32" is open for interpretation as those are not standard types. Better to use `uint32_t` since you have all ready assumed IEEE `float`.

Comment: "Here is a proof that this works:" is not proof, but evidence that it can work.  Other platforms could have failed given the above concerns.

Comment: @ideasman42: oops, on the contrary: since IEEE uses sign+magnitude, the values must **not** be both negative for the comparison as `int` to succeed.

Comment: @ideasman42 If you like, I can delete these comments as I have rolled them into an answer.

Comment: @chqrlie negatives work if `int` is signed magnitude too.  Yes - only on a machine in a silicon graveyard. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

## The answer first

Yes, you can compare a binary representations of `float` as long as they are using IEEE-754 format, integers are 2's complement, you are comparing positive values or positive value with the negative, and you are treating the special cases properly.

[Snippet on Ideone.com in C](http://ideone.com/s1i4rE)

## The explanation

An IEEE-754 float (4 bytes) has the following structure:

```
     s::::::::.......................    meaning
    31                              0    bit #

    s = sign bit, : = exponent, . = mantissa
```

The value is coded as a `mantissa * 2 ^ exponent`. The exponent range is `0x00` to `0xFF`, and it represents values `-127` to `128` (`0x7F` corresponds to `0`).

The mantissa represents *a binary fraction* with an implied `1b` always present to the left of the decimal. Each bit of mantissa represents a value of `2 ^ -(n+1)`, where `n` is an index of a bit from the left. The leftmost bit of mantissa has a value of `0.5`, second on the left `0.25`, third on the left `0.125`, and so on.

The value `0.5` will have mantissa `b0000...` (`b1.0`) and the exponent `0x7E` (`-1`).
The value `0.03` will have mantissa `b1110...` (`b1.1110...`) and the exponent `0x79` (`-6`).
These values would be stored as:

```
0 01111110 00000000000000000000000    (0x3F000000)
0 01111001 11101011100001010001111    (0x3CF5C28F)
```

The lowest value you can store is `1.0 * 2 ^ -127` (all bits of mantissa and exponent are zero). That is a special case and represents a `0`. The exponent value `0xFF` is reserved for `NaN` and `infinity`.

[Floating point number representation](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/floating_point/understanding_floating_point_representation.html)

You can compare a negative `float` value with the positive if you are using `signed int` because the sign flag is being stored in the highest bit for both `signed int` and `float`. You can not compare two negative `float` values like this tho, as the negation of `int` is not being done by inversion of the sign flag only.

Answer (score 0):

As from my understanding, you want to read float number from memory as unsigned/signed integer and I will give you answer for that.

You cannot compare `float` with `signed` or `unsigned` int (32-bit).

For example, number `4` in `int` is represented as `0x00000004` while the same number `4` is represented in float (by IEEE754 standard) as `0x40800000`.

Comment: I think it was about comparing floats with floats, not floats with ints.

Answer (score -3):

It does not matter if you compare uint from the union with float or the float itself. Same rules.

if you have two operations:

```
union {
  float fl;
  uint32_t ui;
} a, b

float a.fl = (math expressions);
float b.fl = (another math expressions); // both giving theoretically the same results

// comparition of

if(a.fl == b.fl) .... //UB - as float shall not be compared for being equal
if(a.ui == b.ui) .... //UB - as ui is an unsigned representation of the bytes of fl
```

Comment: You're misusing the abbreviation UB there especially in the first `if`.

Comment: @Antti Haapala and you do too much semantics. Logically it is UB as the result of such a comparition is unpredictable. It can be true if mathematically a.fl != b.fl and false when using common arithmetic knowledge it should be true.

Comment: @Antti Haapala UB? Really? It has two meanings :  **Unspecified behaviour**  and **Undefined behaviour**. Probably you have never heard about the first one. Read the related documents first.

Comment: `a.fl == b.fl` has *specified behaviour*. It has behaviour that is very much specified by the standard.