# C/C++ - converting a float to byte array such that bytes preserve ordering

Tags: c++, c, floating-point

Is there a way to convert a `float` to an `unsigned char fbytes[8]` such that:

If float value `f1 < f2`, then `fbytes1[i]` should NEVER be greater than `fbytes2[i]` for `0 <= i <= 7`?

The intention behind this is to serialize and store a floating point number and still be able to do comparisons by comparing byte by byte. E.g. even if the float is stored as raw bytes, I can sort rows by simple byte comparison and still preserve order.

Comment: Why do you need that *specific* numeric relationship?

Comment: left fill with zeroes

Comment: I have no idea what is bing asked here. How are you converting the float to an array of bytes?

Comment: @RobertHarvey To serialize and store a floating point number and still be able to do comparisons by comparing byte by byte.

Comment: A single-precision floating point is represented by a sign bit, eight bits for the exponent and 23 bits for the mantissa.  It should be a relatively simple matter to arrange those bits so that the numeric ordering is preserved.  It won't be the relationship you describe in your question, however.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: The [2nd part of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45190635/2410359) addresses OP's goal.

Comment: @jeffreyveon Does the linked answer meet your goal?  Otherwise, please detail why this post is using 8 bytes to do something that should only take 4 - the typical size of a `float`.

Comment: I suspect the most robust solution would be to read the bytes back in to a floating-point variable and then compare the floating-point variables in the usual fashion.  Anything "clever" that avoids that step will likely be slower and will also likely give the incorrect result in some cases.

Comment: @chux: it might take 8 bytes to assure the correct ordering.

Comment: a modern Intel processor does doubles as fast is ints. Why not just treat the data as doubles when it is on your side of the serialization? even if you have to C cast...

Comment: @lakeweb Many modern embedded process lack FP units and such integer based compares are _significantly_ faster.  Of course OP's situation  is not well known.

Comment: Hi @chux yes. I've written a trig lib in integer form for a small micro. The op will have to chime in about his target...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you ignore NANs (which always compare unequal to everything, including themselves), this is simple. Otherwise, it is impossible.

First, convert to a big-endian byte array directly.

The sign bit is the high bit of the first byte. The following bits are the exponent, and then the mantissa.

If the sign bit is not set, set it so that all positive numbers sort after all negative numbers.

Otherwise, apply the `~` operator to all bytes (or maybe do this while it's all packed in a single integer - why do you need bytes anyway?). This will reverse the sort order within the negative numbers, as well as moving them below the positive numbers.

You may also want to coalesce zeros (if the only bit set anywhere is the sign bit, clear it).

Comment: This is pretty much what I thought, but I got thrown by the OP's formula for evaluating order, which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: You need bytes because that's the only **portable** way to dissect values.

Answer (score 2):

If your floating-point implementation uses IEEE-754 (most do), you can take advantage of a subtle design point: if you treat the bits of an IEEE floating-point value as a sign-magnitude representation of an integral value, the usual ordering comparisons on that value will give **exactly** the same order as the corresponding comparisons on the floating-point value, **and** provide a consistent ordering when NaNs are present (positive NaNs are greater than infinity and negative NaNs are less than -infinity). So check the sign bits: if they're different, the positive one is greater; if they're the same, compare the rest as if they were an integral value.